# Normalization of solution of a PDE

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve the following PDE:

```
pde = D[P[x, t], t] + D[J[x, t], x] == 0;
```

```
m1 = 0.6; m2 = 0.9;
J[x_, t_] := 1/2 ((-1 + 2 m1 - 2 x (-1 + m1 + m2)) P[x, t] + (-1 + x) x D[P[x, t], x]);
ic = P[x, 0] == 
   Exp[-((x - 7./10)^2/(1./1000))]/(NIntegrate[Exp[-((x - 7/10)^2/(1/1000))], {x, 0.,1.}]); (*supposed to be a delta function but using an approximation*)
bc1 = (J[x, t] /. x -> 0) == 0.;
bc2 = (J[x, t] /. x -> 1) == 0.;
norm = Integrate[P[x, t], {x, 0, 1}] == 1;
```

Attempted solution:

1. `DSolve` failed to solve it. The analytical solution is here https://arxiv.org/pdf/q-bio/0508045.pdf (check page # 10 (iii))
2. `NDSolve` gave a solution. The approach used is as follows:

```
mol[n_Integer, o_ : "Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}
molfem[measure_ : Automatic] := {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> MaxCellMeasure -> measure}};
nasol = NDSolveValue[{pde, ic, bc1, bc2}, P, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}, Method -> mol[10000, 6]];
nasolfem = NDSolveValue[{pde, ic, bc1, bc2}, P, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}, Method -> molfem[0.0001]];
```

But the solution isn't normalized:
`ListPlot[Table[{t, NIntegrate[nasol[x, t], {x, 0, 1}]}, {t, 0, 10, 1}]]`

```
{{0, 1.}, {1, 0.993899}, {2, 0.971975}, {3, 0.946144}, {4, 0.920094}, {5, 0.894575}, {6, 0.869725}, {7, 0.845557}, {8, 0.82206}, {9, 0.799215}, {10, 0.777005}}
```

If we do the following (which is slow and needs lots of memory):

```
nasol = NDSolveValue[{pde, ic, bc1, bc2}, P, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}, Method -> mol[1000000, 6]];
ListPlot[
 Table[{t, NIntegrate[nasol[x, t], {x, 0, 1}]}, {t, 0, 10, 1}], PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

It's still not normalized.

Questions:

1. Is there an analytical solution?
2. How do I resolve the normalization issue?

Comment: For #1: if you can assume that the dependence over `x` and `t` can be separated in the two functions, you could use the method of separation of variables: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this question we first reproduce solution from the paper [Exact Solution of the Multi-Allelic Diffusion Model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/q-bio/0508045.pdf)

```
pl = x^a (1 - x)^b JacobiP[l, a, b, 1 - 2 x];
cl = JacobiP[l, a, b, 1 - 2 x0] Gamma[2 R + l - 1] Gamma[
    l + 1] (2 R + 2 l - 1)/Gamma[2 m1 + l]/Gamma[2 m2 + l];
a = 2 m1 - 1; b = 2 m2 - 1; R = m1 + m2; {m1 = 0.6, m2 = 0.9, 
 x0 = 0.7, n = 19};
P1 = Sum[cl pl Exp[-1/2 l (2 R + l - 1) t], {l, 0, n}];
```

Note that `pl` are eigenfunctions, while eigenvalues are given by `lambda=1/2 l (2 R + l - 1)`.
Second, let's try to solve the Kolmogorov equation with Mathematica using `DEigensystem` as follows

```
n = 20;

op = With[{m1 = 6/10, m2 = 9/10}, 
   1/2 D[((-1 + 2 m1 - 2 x (-1 + m1 + m2)) (p[x]) + (-1 + x) x D[p[x],
          x]), x]];

{vals, funs} = 
  DEigensystem[{op, DirichletCondition[p[x] == 0, True]}, p[x], {x, 0, 1}, n];
```

We can compare `vals` with the analytical solution shown above as

```
With[{m1 = 6/10, m2 = 9/10}, Table[l (2 (m1 + m2) + l - 1)/2, {l, 0, n - 1}]]

(*Out[]= {0, 3/2, 4, 15/2, 12, 35/2, 24, 63/2, 40, 99/2, 60, 143/2, \
84, 195/2, 112, 255/2, 144, 323/2, 180, 399/2}*)

vals

(*Out[]= {0, 3/2, 4, 15/2, 12, 35/2, 24, 63/2, 40, 99/2, 60, 143/2, \
84, 195/2, 112, 255/2, 144, 323/2, 180, 399/2}*)
```

We see the perfect agreement. But eigenfunction `funs` are not normalized, so normalize it and compute coefficients `c` as follows

```
norm = Table[
   NIntegrate[funs[[i]] funs[[i]], {x, 0, 1}, 
    Method -> "LocalAdaptive"], {i, n}];

ff = Table[
   NIntegrate[
    funs[[i]]/Sqrt[norm[[i]]] funs[[j]]/Sqrt[norm[[j]]], {x, 0, 1}, 
    Method -> "LocalAdaptive"], {i, n}, {j, n}];

dd = Integrate[DiracDelta[x - 7/10] funs, {x, 0, 1}] // N; dn = 
 Table[dd[[i]]/Sqrt[norm[[i]]], {i, Length[dd]}];

c = LinearSolve[ff, dn];
```

Finally, we define the analytical solution in a form

```
P = Sum[c[[i]] funs[[i]]/Sqrt[norm[[i]]] Exp[-vals[[i]] t], {i, 
       n}]; 
normP = NIntegrate[P /. t -> 0, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"];
```

Now we can compare two analytical solutions `P` (blue solid line), and `P1`(red dashed line) in one plot for different times as

```
Table[Plot[Evaluate[{P/normP, P1} /. t -> t0], {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> t0, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Blue}, {Red, Dashed}}], {t0, .0, 1.5, .1}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

We also can plot these data in 3D

```
{Plot3D[P, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0.05, 1.5}, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot3D[P1, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0.05, 1.5}, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

Check normalization

```
Table[NIntegrate[P1, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"], {t, 0, 10,
    1}] // Quiet 
{1.00007, 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}


Table[NIntegrate[P/normP, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"], {t, 
   0, 10, 1}] // Quiet

(*Out[]= {1., 0.999981, 0.999981, 0.999981, 0.999981, 0.999981, \
0.999981, 0.999981, 0.999981, 0.999981, 0.999981}*)
```

**Update 1** Let's consider the numerical solution to this problem with Mathematica FEM. First, we prepare handmade mesh as follows

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

```
xmin = 0.; xmax = 1.; reg = 
 ImplicitRegion[xmin <= x <= xmax, {x}]; 
mesh =ToElementMesh[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 1. 10^-3];
mesh1 = ToElementMesh[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 1. 10^-4];
mesh2 = ToElementMesh[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 1. 10^-5];
```

Next we compute 3 solutions with using `mesh,mesh1,mesh2` and initial condition `p[x, 0] == P /. t -> .05`, we have

```
pde = D[p[x, t], t] + D[J[x, t], x] == 0; 
J[x_, t_] := 
 1/2 ((-1 + 2 m1 - 2 x (-1 + m1 + m2)) p[x, t] + (-1 + x) x D[p[x, t],
       x]);
ic = p[x, 0] == P /. t -> .05; sol = 
 NDSolve[{pde, ic, 
   DirichletCondition[p[x, t] == 0, x == xmin || x == xmax]}, p, 
  Element[{x}, mesh], {t, 0, 1.5}];sol1 = 
 NDSolve[{pde, ic, 
   DirichletCondition[p[x, t] == 0, x == xmin || x == xmax]}, p, 
  Element[{x}, mesh1], {t, 0, 1.5}];sol2 = 
 NDSolve[{pde, ic, 
   DirichletCondition[p[x, t] == 0, x == xmin || x == xmax]}, p, 
  Element[{x}, mesh2], {t, 0, 1.5}];
```

Finally we show in one plot analytical solution `P`(*1*), and numerical solutions `sol,sol1,sol2`- *2,3,4* as

```
Plot[Evaluate[{P, 
    p[x, t - .05] /. {sol[[1]], sol1[[1]], sol2[[1]]}} /. 
   t -> 1.5], {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 3]

We can see from this picture, that the numerical solution approaches the analytical solution with an increasing number of mesh elements. Also, we can compute the norm for every solution at `t=1.45`

```
normp = 
 NIntegrate[p[x, 1.45] /. sol[[1]], {x, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]

(*Out[]= 0.988646*)
normp1 = 
 NIntegrate[p[x, 1.45] /. sol1[[1]], {x, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]

(*Out[]= 0.99864*)
 normp2 = 
 NIntegrate[p[x, 1.45] /. sol2[[1]], {x, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]

(*Out[]= 1.00392*)
```

**Update 2.** We also can compute eigenfunctions and eigenvalues with using `NDEigensystem` as follows

```
n=20;
op1 = With[{m1 = 6/10, 
   m2 = 9/10}, {-1/
     2 D[((-1 + 2 m1 - 2 x (-1 + m1 + m2)) (p[x]) + (-1 + x) x D[p[x],
          x]), x], DirichletCondition[p[x] == 0, True]}]; {vals1, 
  funs1} = 
 NDEigensystem[op1, p[x], {x, 0, 1}, n, 
  Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.00001}}}, 
    "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", "MaxIterations" -> 10000}}];
```

Using these functions we can define numerical solutions in a form (code is same as above for analytical solution)

```
norm = Table[
  NIntegrate[funs1[[i]]^2, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"], {i, 
   Length[vals1]}]

 ff = 
 Table[NIntegrate[
   funs1[[i]]/Sqrt[norm[[i]]] funs1[[j]]/Sqrt[norm[[j]]], {x, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> "LocalAdaptive"], {i, n}, {j, n}];
dd = Integrate[DiracDelta[x - 7/10] funs1, {x, 0, 1}] // N; dn = 
 Table[dd[[i]]/Sqrt[norm[[i]]], {i, Length[dd]}];
c = LinearSolve[ff, dn];
P = Sum[c[[i]] funs1[[i]]/Sqrt[norm[[i]]] Exp[vals[[i]] t], {i, n}];
```

Visualization

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[P], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0.05, 1.5}, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Figure 4]

This picture looks very similar to the analytical solution, but if we compute the norm, then we have large discrepancies with the analytical solution,

```
Table[NIntegrate[P, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"] // 
   Quiet, {t, 0, 10, 1}] 

(*{1.01157, 1.00819, 0.997508, 0.984611, 0.971379, 0.958216, 0.945208, 0.932372, 0.919709, 0.907218, 0.894896}*)
```

The problem is that `vals1` computed with a high error compare to the analytical one,

```
vals1

(* {-0.0136747, -1.53703, -4.06629, -7.60031, -12.1385, -17.6803, -24.2255, -31.774, -40.3254, -49.8796, -60.4365, -71.9961, -84.5582, -98.1227, -112.69, -128.259, -144.83, -162.404, -180.98, -200.557}*) 
-vals
{0, -(3/2), -4, -(15/2), -12, -(35/2), -24, -(63/2), -40, -(99/
  2), -60, -(143/2), -84, -(195/2), -112, -(255/2), -144, -(323/
  2), -180, -(399/2)}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it. I actually have lots of questions but let me start with two basic ones: 1. How were you able to read the eigenfunction and eigenvalue from the solution? 2. Could you please explain how you were able to formulate the PDE problem as Eigensystem problem?

Comment: @sra Please, pay attention that in the paper you cited they expressed solution in a form $P=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}c_l p_l(x)e^{-\lambda_l t}$. If we put this expression in PDE, then we come to the eigenvalues problem as it mentioned above.  Your first question is not so clear. Do you interested in how to separate $p_l, \lambda_l$ from analytical solution?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I understand eigenvalue formulation now. However, I still do not get `DEigensystem`. Let's say that if I change m1 = m2=0.5 then mathematica fails to solve it. It has to do with the `DirichletCondition` because for m1-m2 p[x] != 0 at x=0 and x=1. Can `DEigensystem` be used to solve it for general m1 and m2?

Comment: @sra No, `DEigensystem` can't be used for arbitrary `m1,m2`. It is why I add section Update 2.

Comment: For `m1 = m2 ` the `p[x]==0` boundary condition (BC) does not work. For example:
 `op = With[{m1 = 5/10, m2 = 5/10}, 
   1/2 D[((-1 + 2 m1 - 2 x (-1 + m1 + m2)) (p[x]) + (-1 + x) x D[p[x],x]), x]];
{vals, funs} = DEigensystem[{op, DirichletCondition[p[x] == 0 , True]}, 
   p[x], {x, 0, 1}, n];` How do we impose BC in such case?

Comment: @sra As I understand reading paper cited, they always used `DirichletCondition[p[x] == 0 , True]`.  Fortunately, we have an analytical solution. Why do you need something else?

Comment: For me, it's an exercise to learn how to use Mathematica to solve PDE. Thanks to you, I learned a  lot. I want to solve this for M> 4 and compute the stationary state for M=4,5,6 for different mutation rates. Is it fair to assume `DEigensystem` does not work for `m1=m2` with `DirichletCondition[p[x] == 0 , True]` ?

Comment: The problem for $M\ge 4$ is quite different from discussed above. Also pay attention that `DEigensystem` is not so powerful tool. Sometimes it breaks even on the simplest problems like `m1=m2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will work on $M\geq 4$ and see how it goes. Btw, there's a typo: `P = Sum[c[[i]] funs1[[i]]/Sqrt[norm[[i]]] Exp[vals[[i]] t], {i, n}];`  vals should be vals1, right?

Comment: @sra Do you mean last expression for `P`? Yes, it should be `vals1`, but it more accurate with analytical expression `vals`.

Answer (score 2):

answer #2(only FEM-solution works!)

```
molfem[measure_ : Automatic] := {"MethodOfLines","SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> MaxCellMeasure -> measure}};

nasolfem =NDSolveValue[{pde, ic, bc1, bc2}, P, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10} ,Method-> molfem[0.01 ] ];
Plot3D[nasolfem[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All,AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "P[x,t]"}]
```

[image]

scaling function

```
mw =.
mw[t_?NumericQ] :=Block[{x},NIntegrate[nasolfem[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, Method -> "FiniteElement"]]
Plot[mw[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotLabel -> "Scaling function mw[t]"]
```

[image]

normalized solution

```
Show[Table[
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x, t, nasolfem[x, t]/mw[t]}], {x, 0, 1} ,BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Hue[t ]] , {t,Subdivide[0, 1.5, 15 3] // Rest}], PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1.5}, {0, 5}}, 
PlotLabel ->"normalized solution \!\(\*FractionBox[\(P[x, t]\),\(mw[t]\)]\)", AxesLabel -> {x, t, P/mw}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much (+1). :)

Comment: @AlexTrounev You 're welcome. FEM solution only roughly approximates your exact solution. Why these differences?

Comment: Use  handmade mesh and `DirichletCondition[P[x, t] == 0, True]`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks, that makes it easier

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thanks a lot for helping out.